# Первый bundle пуст

Tags: java, android-bundle

Передаю данные из фрагмента в фрагмент.

```
Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.bookFragment);
    
    Fragment fragment = new BookFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("target", book.getLink());
    bundle.putString("image", book.getImage());
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    
    Log.i("CUSTOM ADAPTER", "SET BUNDLE");
    
    ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment).commit();
```

Получаю в методе OnCreate

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

Log.i("CUSTOM ADAPTER", "GET BUNDLE: " + bundle);
```

Вот лог

```
2020-06-15 03:34:55.213 1407-1407/com.d.b I/CUSTOM ADAPTER: SET BUNDLE
2020-06-15 03:34:55.271 1407-1407/com.d.b I/CUSTOM ADAPTER: GET BUNDLE: null
2020-06-15 03:34:55.361 1407-1407/com.d.b I/CUSTOM ADAPTER: GET BUNDLE: Bundle[{target=/book/14470, image=/i/book/19/12/16134.jpg}]
```

Как понятно из вопроса, у меня первый bundle почему-то пустой. Как это исправить? Для дальнейшей работы с переменными мне нужны значения, иначе постоянно будет вылетать exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation Component сам создаёт фрагмент и управляет транзакциями. Так что у вас сначала происходит переход на фрагмент без аргументов через Navigation Component, а потом вы его вручную зачем то заменяете на новый.

Всё что нужно сделать, это передать аргументы при навигации и избавиться от лишнего кода

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("target", book.getLink());
bundle.putString("image", book.getImage());
// Log.i("CUSTOM ADAPTER", "SET BUNDLE");
Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.bookFragment, bundle);
```

Comment: О, спасибо, я не знал. Не так давно начал изучать Java и программирование под Android, поэтому многого ещё не понимаю.